# Checkstyle: Should single-line Java comments have a space after the opening two slashes?

Tags: java, comments, checkstyle

There does not appear to be a [default Checkstyle check](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/sun_checks.xml) nor a [default Google Checkstyle check](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) to ensure that single-line comments are formatted like so:

```
// comment text
```

and not as so:

```
//comment text
```

This convention is implied in Section 3.7 "Comments" of the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.7):

> 3.7. Comments
>
> There are two kinds of comments:
>
> ```
> /* text */
>
> A traditional comment: all the text from the ASCII characters /* to the ASCII characters */ is ignored (as in C and C++).
>
> // text
>
> An end-of-line comment: all the text from the ASCII characters // to the end of the line is ignored (as in C++).
> ```

Summarily it appears to be *de rigueur* in Java itself, for example in http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java

This is consistent and therefore clearly deliberate.

Is it therefore objectively incorrect to omit the space between the two slashes and the comment text?

Is there a well-known Checkstyle checks extension library which contains a check for this?

Comment: There isn't a convention in JLS, even an implied one. JLS doesn't instruct how you format your code, it's a language specification. Even if in JLS they put opening `{` on a new line, it doesn't mean anyone implied that everyone should do the same.

Comment: Relevant open issues on Checkstyle's github: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/7388 and https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/6593

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thanks for your opinion on this. However, there's an unwavering consistency in the code snippets given in the JLS and the code comments in the JDK to follow two slashes with a space. Given the definition of convention (noun) as "a way in which something is usually done" (source: Google 'define convention') I think I am correct in claiming this to be a convention. It is legal to omit the space, but it appears unconventional to do so, and on that basis I am surprised there is no CheckStyle check for it (there are checks for similar things which are also legal yet unconventional).

Comment: The point I made is that there's no convention in JLS. There might be one in OpenJDK and a bunch of other places. But it is obviously not objectively correct or incorrect to do any particular formatting for comments. As for the check, your link provides precisely the reason why it's not there (yet) - no one cared enough to add one.

Comment: The question "is it objectively incorrect" is definitely answered "no", because no matter of style has an objective answer; if that answer is unsatisfying then the question is a matter of opinion. For what it's worth, I'd say that requiring a space would be bad for the case where you want to comment out of a line of code by putting `//` in front of it; spaces would just be wasted extra keypresses. In that case, the comment is meant to stop that code from executing without deleting it from the source, not to be something that needs to be readable in order to explain how the program works.

Comment: Comments are not code. Do whatever you fancy.

Comment: Could you change your question to "How to enforece a space after the opening slashes"? Then, I have the answer (with a sort of a quick hack, but works without patching Checkstyle)